# How to get the final result of a multi module project in the root project directory folder?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a a multi modules project such as:

```
project:
    - module1
    - module2
    - packaging
```

The module 1 and 2 respectively generate a jar and the packaging use the maven assembly to put everything into a zip file.

The result looks like:

```
final-archive.zip:
    - module1.jar
    - module2.jar
```

The issue I'm facing is that the resulting zip is in the **packaging** folder of my project and not in the root folder of the project directory.

How can I have the final result of my build at the place I wish to ?

The main pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>groupId :: Name :: Project</name>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>


    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
        <module>packaging</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

The packaging pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>groupId :: Project :: Packaging</name>

    <artifactId>packaging</artifactId>

    <properties>
    

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The assembly

```
<assembly
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/2.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
    <id>packaging-assembly</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>../module1/target/jar-module1-${version}.jar</source>
        </file>
        <file>
            <source>../module2/target/jar-module2-${version}.jar</source>
        </file>
    </files>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I have a Jenkins pipeline that push the result of a maven build to nexus. I assume it takes the result of the build of the main pom.

Comment: No it will deploy all artifacts ... not related to main. furthermore the question do you use `mvn deploy` or are you using to deploy via Jenkins? Take the one view Maven...furthermore the parent will be executed first so this setup can never work correctly...

Comment: I see didn't know this. Guess I don't need this post then. The groovy code that is called on Jenkins use mvn deploy yes.

Comment: I will close the post, ty for your time time guys.

Comment: The problem seemed to be that in your package module you have not defined any dependency to get the correct build order of your module (m1, m2, package) and I suppose there are WARNINGs in your build that it does not find things ... etc. Accessing jar files via file is a bad idea that will not work...wrote about a time about it (https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2013/09/28/build-smells-maven-assembly-plugin/). maybe things have changed over the time ...

Comment: No there was  no issue, what I printed of the pom.xml are only limited version because I thougth the remaining was irelevant. This whole post was a wrong assumption of a Jenkins that I don't have anymore. I changed nothing. Weird.